# Multiple searchable activities with suggestions

Tags: android, search, android-activity

I have app with 2 activities - 2 different listviews with different data and I would like to have searching via actionbar in both. Also, both should contain suggestions support.

So far, it seems that I can have only one searchable.xml that is always bound to only one activity:

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="XXXSuggestionsContentProvider"
    android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW">
</searchable>
```

Is there a way I can have multiple searchables?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, works just perfectly for me.

Inflate menu like this in activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
            //REFRESH ADAPTER WITH NEW FILTERED LIST HERE
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
            //REFRESH ADAPTER WITH NEW FILTERED LIST HERE
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Menu should look something like this for it to work:

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:grupete="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        grupete:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/search"
        grupete:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

Hope I could help you!

Best regards,

pedrovic90